# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP and NON WWW to WWW

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

I have a problem with my redirects and im guessing its because i keep copy and pasting my htaccess rules.

I need to redirect all https traffic to http, and all non www to www. I also have some more rules to make pretty links

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule (.*\.php)\.$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^people/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^people-in-(.*) /people.php?county=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ties\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ties.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ties\.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.ties.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

into a single rule that needs to be *right below `RewriteEngine On`*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ties\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRUle ^(.*)$ http://www.ties.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```